# Fullscreen Background Image with React JS Div and Component

Tags: css, reactjs, components, background-image

I'm sure the answer is right in front of me, but I have searched and searched for hours and have been unable to come up with a fix. I am wondering how to have my background image fill the whole screen. It fills most of the screen, except where the header would be. I can get the full screen background image, only when I comment out the "Form" component. When I go to inspect the portion that is not filled, it says it shows as html, which I suspect is pulled from the index.html file in the public folder. I would greatly appreciate any and all help on this.

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Form from './Form';
import wallstreet from './images/wallstreet.png';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="overlay"
      style={{backgroundImage: `url(${wallstreet})`}} />
            <Form />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**App.css**

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=PT+Sans&display=swap');

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

**Form.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import FormSignup from './FormSignup';
import FormSuccess from './FormSuccess';
import './Form.css';

const Form = () => {
    const [isSubmitted, setIsSubmitted] = useState(false)

    function submitForm() {
        setIsSubmitted(true);
    }
    return (
        <>
<div className="form-container">
    <span className="close-btn">x</span>
    <div className="form-content-left">
    <img className='form-img' src='images/bullish.png' alt='bullish' />
    </div>
    {!isSubmitted ? (<FormSignup submitForm=
            {submitForm} />) : <FormSuccess />}
</div>
        </>
    );
};

export default Form;
```

**Form.css**

```
.form-container {
    margin: 100px auto;
    width: 1000px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 7px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 600px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  }
  
  .close-btn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 2%;
    right: 3%;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    z-index: 1;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  .form-content-left {
    background: linear-gradient(
      90deg,
      rgb(39, 176, 255) 0%,
      rgb(0, 232, 236) 100%
    );
    border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .form-img {
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
  
  .form-img-2 {
    width: 60%;
    height: 60%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
  
  .form-success {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-top: 80px;
    color: #fff;
  }
  
  .form-content-right {
    border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
    position: relative;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(40, 40, 40) 0%, rgb(17, 17, 17) 100%);
  }
  
  .form {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 90%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  .form h1 {
    font-size: 1rem;
    text-align: start;
    width: 80%;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    color: #fff;
  }
  
  .form-inputs {
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
    width: 80%;
  }
  
  .form-inputs p {
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    margin-top: 0.5rem;
    color: #f00e0e;
  }
  
  .form-label {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    color: #fff;
  }
  
  .form-input {
    display: block;
    padding-left: 10px;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 2px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
  }
  
  .form-input::placeholder {
    color: #595959;
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  
  .form-input-btn {
    width: 80%;
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background: linear-gradient(
      90deg,
      rgb(39, 176, 255) 0%,
      rgb(0, 232, 236) 100%
    );
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
  
  .form-input-btn:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background: linear-gradient(
      90deg,
      rgb(39, 143, 255) 0%,
      rgb(12, 99, 250) 100%
    );
    transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  }
  
  .form-input-login {
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    width: 80%;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .form-input-login a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #27cdff;
    font-weight: 6
```

00;
}

Comment: Can you make the div with className app have the background image instead of some random div? I think this would then fill the whole background.

Comment: @sidc you are correct in your solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try 100vh and 100vw along with position absolute.
also search if any of the parent element is having relative position

Comment: I tried that as well and it did not work. Looks like sid c had the solution. Thanks